# Mapping array using d3.range.map and nodes

Tags: d3.js, nodes

I am struggling to integrate my data into this function. My issue has to do with the mapping the data to i. It seems to draw a few but not all of them.

example:

```
var n = 291, // total number of nodes
    m = 10; // number of distinct clusters

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(m))
    .rangePoints([0, width], 1);

var nodes = d3.range(n).map(function() {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m),
      v = (i + 1) / m * -Math.log(Math.random());
  return {
    radius: Math.sqrt(v) * maxRadius,
    color: color(i),
    cx: x(i),
    cy: height / 2
  };
});
```

My code:

```
codeArray = [0,0,1,3.1,4,4.2,7,9]; (and so forth, 291 values)

var nodes = d3.range(n).map(function(j) {
  var i = codeArray[j];
  return {
    radius: 5,
    cx: x(i),
    cy: height / 2
  };
});
```

Error message:

[image: error message]

Comment: It looks like the domain for your x scale contains only 10 values and you're trying to pass 291 values.